# Select the rows where variable x starts with 65 (teradata)

Tags: sql, select, teradata

I have a table with a column named x that includes numbers for all my observations. I now want to select only the variables that start with 65.

I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE x REGEXP '^[65]'
```

and different versions of like/isnumeric, but I cant figure a clean way out.

Comment: That does not work as my string contain a lot more than just the 65.

Comment: that does not work, the variable is on the format 65123831283xxxxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is actually a Teradata DBMS your inital query will result in an error message because there's no `REGEXP` (but there's a `REGEXP_SIMILAR`).

You don't need a regular expression to compare the first two digits. If the datatype of `x` is numeric you must cast it to a string first:

```
WHERE TRIM(x) LIKE '65%'
WHERE CAST(x AS VARCHAR(20)) LIKE '65%'
```

If it's a VarChar you might have some leading spaces (which are really bad):

```
WHERE TRIM(x) LIKE '65%'
```

Comment: Thanks, the WHERE CAST(x AS VARCHAR(20)) LIKE '65%'

is what I was after

Answer (score 1):

You may use like or left to find start with prefix

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '65%'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE LEFT(COLUMN_NAME, 2) = '65'
```

Comment: The first one does not work as partial string matching requires character operands... The second one does nothing at all and even if I include a %, it returns nothing.

Comment: the first one only finds those started with 65 not partial 65 and second one also doing the same. Would you be more specific what you want? From your question you just want to select all rows those started with 65 I assume!!!!

Comment: Do you have any specific characters before 65 in your records you wanna overlook for select???

Answer (score 0):

**Tested and working.**

```
SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE concat("_",x) like '_65%'
```

Could be slow if your table is very big, because it does not use the indexes and performs full table scan.

Comment: That tries to find a column named _ in the table. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My code filters the table called "someTable" and shows all records where the column x starts with 65. My code does not try to find a column in a table.

Comment: I find that strange as I get: SELECT Failed. 5628:  Column _ not found in table22.

Comment: @D.Loo did you remove the " from "_" by mistake ? I actually executed this SQL and it worked. Just copy paste and change the table name.

Comment: no I copied and then pasted it. Are you using teradata sql assistant?

Comment: Make sure you are on the correct database.Works fine for me.I use MySql workbench. Just change the name of the table to yours, make sure U have a column named x and